# Change email address in CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-csv

I am writing PowerShell code to export email addresses to a csv file and edit them. I've written the following:

```
# Script to get all DLs and email addresses in csv file
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'groupcategory -eq "distribution"' -Properties * |
    select Name, mail |
    Export-csv "C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv"

# Following will import the csv, make new column as proxy and save the file
# as update.csv 
Import-Csv "C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv" |
    Select-Object "Name", "mail", @{n = "proxy"; e = "mail"} |
    Export-Csv "c:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members-Updated.csv" -NoTypeInfo

# Following script can import the csv and set proxy addresses from proxy
# column 
Import-Csv "c:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members-Updated.csv" |
    Foreach {
        Get-ADGroup $_.Name | Set-ADGroup -Add @{
            proxyaddresses = ($_.proxy -split ";")
        }
   }
```

Now, I would like to add 2 more features in the script:

- update domain for existing mail column e.g. update mail address form test@abc.com to test@xyz.com
- Add SMTP:test@xyz.com;smtp:test@abc.com" as Proxy mail address, so that xyz become primary mail address and abc as proxy domain

So assuming my DL name is "DL Test" email is "test@abc.com" => The script should update the email address of DL to "test@xyz.com" and add "smtp:test@abc.com" as proxy mail address

Can someone please advise, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part where you have written:

```
select-object "Name", "mail", @{n = "proxy"; e = "mail"}|
```

The `proxy` part is called a *calculated property*. The first two with just names `Name` and `Mail` are copied directly from the input objects, but using the `@{..}` syntax, you can put code to calculate a new value instead.

So you can use this to achieve both your desired changes:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv' | 

  Select-Object -Property Name, 
   @{Label='Mail';  Expression={$_.Mail -replace 'abc', 'xyz'}}, 
   @{Label='Proxy'; Expression={"SMTP:$($_.Mail -replace 'abc', 'xyz');smtp:$($_.Mail)"}}|

  Export-csv 'C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks @tessellatingHeckler.. It worked perfectly  fine

Comment: @RaviSingh great :)